# R Statistics Trying to Call Element from Vector Using Elements In Another Dataframe

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I probably worded this question terribly and I know there is a really simple solution but I am horrible at everything and can't find it because I suck at trying to find the words for this stuff I am sorry in advance for what is crap code anyway here's what I am trying to do.

```
X1 <- c(0,0,1,1,0)
X2 <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
X3 <- c(0,1,1,1,1)

lookup <- data.frame (X1, X2, X3) 
#This above here creates a data frame with 5 rows and 3 columns with binary answers.

Match <- 1:(15)
P1 <- rep(1:5, each=3)
X1 <- rep(1:3,length.out=15)
X1 <- paste("X", X1, sep="")
Data <- data.frame(Match, X1, P1) 
#This above creates a dataframe where it shows every possible match up of row and column for a total of 15 rows (5 people with 3 items).
```

What I want to do is pull the element from the lookup table into a new column that shows the result of the match up of P1 and X1. Something like this:

```
Data$Result <- lookup[1,'X3']
```

The above works like I want it to but it only works for row 1 and X3 (question 3). But when I try to replace those things to change by row depending on what the column values are it's just a mess either returning null or not the result at all. Here's what I tried:

```
Data$Result <- lookup["P1","X1"] #this doesn't work
Data$Result <- lookup[Data$P1,Data$X1] #and this doesn't work
Data$Result <- lookup[P1,X1] #and this doesn't work
```

I'm sure there's a really easy answer and I'm just really stupid it would be super nice if someone could give me some help on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have edited your question a bit, i.e. formatted your code as code. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Now to your question. In your 'lookup' data frame, do the rows correspond to  `Data$P` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a left join.
See suggestion below.
Also, a small word to your variabel naming. I would recommend using only small letters, no capitals, makes it easier for coding. (e.g., `data$match`)

```
X1 <- c(0,0,1,1,0)
X2 <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
X3 <- c(0,1,1,1,1)
P1 <- as.integer(1:5)
lookup <- data.frame (P1, X1, X2, X3) #I have added this column because I think this is how your lookup is corresponding to your data

require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

lookup_long <- gather(lookup, 'X' , 'answer', X1:X3) #making data tidy (one observation/variable per row)

left_join(Data, lookup_long, by = 'P1')

   Match X1 P1  X answer
1      1  0 P1 X1      0
2      1  0 P1 X2      1
3      1  0 P1 X3      0
4      2  0 P2 X1      0
5      2  0 P2 X2      0
6      2  0 P2 X3      1
7      3  1 P3 X1      1
8      3  1 P3 X2      0
9      3  1 P3 X3      1
10     4  1 P4 X1      1
11     4  1 P4 X2      1
12     4  1 P4 X3      1
13     5  0 P5 X1      0
14     5  0 P5 X2      0
15     5  0 P5 X3      1
16     6  0 P1 X1      0
17     6  0 P1 X2      1
18     6  0 P1 X3      0
19     7  0 P2 X1      0
20     7  0 P2 X2      0
21     7  0 P2 X3      1
22     8  1 P3 X1      1
23     8  1 P3 X2      0
24     8  1 P3 X3      1
25     9  1 P4 X1      1
26     9  1 P4 X2      1
27     9  1 P4 X3      1
28    10  0 P5 X1      0
29    10  0 P5 X2      0
30    10  0 P5 X3      1
31    11  0 P1 X1      0
32    11  0 P1 X2      1
33    11  0 P1 X3      0
34    12  0 P2 X1      0
35    12  0 P2 X2      0
36    12  0 P2 X3      1
37    13  1 P3 X1      1
38    13  1 P3 X2      0
39    13  1 P3 X3      1
40    14  1 P4 X1      1
41    14  1 P4 X2      1
42    14  1 P4 X3      1
43    15  0 P5 X1      0
44    15  0 P5 X2      0
45    15  0 P5 X3      1
```

Comment: That looks like it's doing what I need it to do. I am having trouble with installing the packages mentioned because I fail at everything but once I am done trouble shooting that I'll see if I can get it working with my data which I think it will. Thanks so much for the feedback!

Comment: What are your problems installing the packages?? Is this technical or do you not know how to install packages ?? Do you have the latest R version installed?

Comment: Both give me some "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’" thing but there's other people who have that error so following whatever they tried and am trying to update all my packages which was suggested so that's taking forever. If that doesn't work I'll play around with where my packages are or the version installed. I think I can figure it out eventually so no need to trouble yourself, the suggestion above already been a great help.

Comment: Well good luck with sorting this out, can only recommend having [tag:tidyverse] installed. Otherwise have a look at merge()

Comment: if you’re happy with an answer, it’s nice to either upvote or accept it - you can do this with the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: I can't upvote because I'm a noob but once I double check it runs I'll do the check mark thing. Thanks again!

Comment: haha yeah sorry forgot about this restriction. good luck sorting your packages out. Maybe clean reinstall R? have you tried simply install.packages(„package“)?

Comment: I managed to get tidyverse working by installing about 5 other packages and your code works great thanks so much!